# How to unit-test for assert() failing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, assert, idioms, doctest

I want to unit-test some code which uses `assert()` occasionally. Specifically, I want to make sure that certain commands do indeed trigger an assert. But - I don't actually want the program to be aborted. (If that happened I would need both to ensure program abortion from outside the program and have a different program for each such testcase.)

I also know that `assert()` is a macro, so if the code I'm testing is header-only, I could theoretically write some kind of replacement macro to trigger a failure using my unit-testing library ([doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/)).

My question:

- Perhaps doctest already has some facility for this kind of testing?
- If not, is there some idiomatic way of implementing assert-firing-tests? Perhaps with other testing frameworks/libraries, which I could adapt?

Note: I've noticed [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1116045/1593077) that Google Test has some kind of related facility, [ASSERT_DEATH](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/8b4817e3df3746a20502a84580f661ac448821be/googletest/docs/advanced.md), but it's not clear to me that it does what I want to do.

Comment: The ASSERT_DEATH documentation you linked to seems to say it is suitable for exactly this purpose

Comment: @JMAA: It's not clear to me how it does what it does, and whether the process actually aborts, with the google test framework perhaps doing something magical to handle that (e.g. parent process). But if you can elaborate, I'd be mocu obliged.

Comment: GoogleTest deathtests [are indeed executed as a subprocess](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#how-it-works). I'm not sure what `assert()` does exactly, but presumably it exits with a standard exit code (which you can test in death test) and it returns an error message (which you can also test).

Answer (score 2):

In general, what you can do is spawn a child process, perform the operations there, and test in the parent process whether the child terminated successfully or not, and possibly check any output generated by the child. I would assume that's what Google's test does.

There is no standard way in C++ for spawning sub-processes. The standard doesn't acknowledge the existence of other processes. Multi tasking operating systems will provide an API for this. In POSIX standard, child processes can be created with the `fork` function.

Comment: So, indeed, that would be a robust way to test for "death". But what about my limited case, of the `assert()` macro, when testing header-only code?

Comment: @einpoklum Changing standard macros would not be allowed by the language. That said, it's effectively you taking charge and creating your own slightly different language implementation, in which case you are responsible for it to do what you want it to do.

Comment: eerorkia: It's just a unit test, don't be so uptight :-P

Comment: @einpoklum It's "just a unit test", which you write to make sure your real code works correctly. If you aren't sure unit test works correctly, it's worthless to write it.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm just telling you what standard doesn't allow. You can decide how uptight you want to be regarding the standard conformance of your unit tests.